# Can a moderator delete answers from others on his own question?

Tags: discussion

This scenario:

> A moderator is asking a question like "How to detect a program in
>   Windows 10, that uses Process Hollowing?", but if there are answers
>   to his/her post is he/she able to delete answers from the question the moderator himselve posted?

This fact would not be useful because the person is asking the question, so he/she is the person who ask for help and thus uses the vote/downvote functionality without extra candies especially this one.

What i think that would be better instead of the current system:
[image]

<sup>"Knowledge makes a man unfit to be a slave.”
- Frederick Douglass</sup>

Comment: Your post is a little hard to understand currently. There are not answers inside a question, but answers to a question. Also answer posts are only removed if they are not answers as per our site criteria.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all moderators can do this. It's part of the trust sites place in moderators.

In reality if we think an answer on one of our posts should be deleted we ask one of the other mods to take a look and see if they agree. That way we provide governance. Additionally, all mod actions are logged so any other site mod, 10k-ers, CMs or any SE staff can see them, so there is a strong audit trail.

If a mod "went rogue" - which hasn't happened here, but I think has once or twice across the whole network, they can be removed and their actions reverted as necessary.

But as Anders pointed out, it hasn't happened here, and is unlikely to, so I'd really not worry about it :-)

Comment: But is what i just added not better?

Comment: No - what you propose currently exists. All except the removing mod privileges. So you are trying to solve a non-existent problem by breaking functionality

Comment: This was rather meaned to be a suggestion, but if it is already applied yeah then everything is  ok!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know, but I would guess that they can delete answers on their own question. But is that really an issue?

First, moderators have been elected becuase we trust them. And if one of them should make a poor judgement call, there are three others who can handle it. Plus all +10k users who can see deleted posts.

Second, it was about 2.5 years since the last time a moderator asked a question. So this feels very much like a theoretical issue without practical importance.

Comment: I would't say this will happen in reality, but the fact that options are availible is unnecessary to use on own questions

Comment: If something will never happend in reality, wasting time and resources on stopping it would be unnecesary. If you disagree, I have some ghost insurance to sell you...

Comment: What would be better is a correction from other moderators, as you said